# How can i apply HTML localStorage to these innerHtml cels?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I don´t know how to apply a localStorage to innerHTML. I have a form that works, but when i **reload the page** i lose the data.

I am building an app with a Js Framework **Electron.js**, using **Xel** toolkit. It is the html, it is a button for store a complete `<form>`:

```
<x-button toggled id="agree-button" onclick="AddItem()">
   <x-label>Save</x-label>
</x-button>
```

Javascript

```
function AddItem(){
    const currentTable = document.getElementById("table2"),
    newRow = currentTable.insertRow(currentTable.length),
    cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
    cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
    cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
    cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
    cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4),
    cel6 = newRow.insertCell(5),
    name = document.getElementById("p_name").value,
    id = document.getElementById("p_id").value,
    description = document.getElementById("p_description").value,
    dir = document.getElementById("p_dir").value,
    email = document.getElementById("p_email").value,
    total = document.getElementById("p_total").value;

    cel1.textContent = name;
    cel2.textContent = id;
    cel3.textContentL = description;
    cel4.textContent = dir;
    cel5.textContent = email;
    cel6.textContent = total;
}
```

trying to apply localStorage in this way:

```
...

var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
if (name !== null){
  document.querySelector("p_name").value;
}
```

Comment: Have you even looked at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? It's ridiculously easy.

Comment: Also, if the string data you are working with doesn't contain any HTML, you shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` as there are security and performance implications to its use. Instead, use `.textContent`.

Comment: sure, i did it as suggested in documentation but it doesn´t work for me when i reload my page, the row disapears.

Comment: Well since you aren't showing us your attempt at using it, we really can't tell you what you are doing wrong. Did you simply save the entire row's HTML?

Comment: i hope in the what i edited can you understand.

Comment: You've shown code that attempts to get something out of `localStorage`. Where is the code that you are using that puts something into `localStorage` in the first place? Show us ***all*** the relevant code here (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).

Comment: Okay , i explained all.

Comment: I still don't see any code that ***sets*** anything into `localStorage`. You can't get something out of `localStorage` that you never put into it in the first place. Read the documentation I linked to to see how this works.